# Gesture recognition for website

Tags: javascript, gesture-recognition, hammer.js, reveal.js

I'm working on swipe gesture recognition for my website.
So, i downloaded sample code of `reveal.js` from [here](https://github.com/willy-vvu/reveal.js) . And i used sample demo of this code, but it's not detecting my hand proper in sometime.
Is there problem in my webcam? or
code does have slow response? or
Is there any other library available for this?

Comment: Consider trying to explain what you have tried and providing code samples instead of just stating it isn't working - no one has any idea what is not working for you...

Comment: Can you please check the demo http://revealjs.herokuapp.com/#/?

Comment: So you're saying it only works sometimes. In that GitHub project it states "the algorithms are only about 80% accurate".

Answer (score 0):

After numerous attempts at finding a highly-compatible library to get the most effective and efficient control of a touch device, I ended up using 'touchSwipe' by 'Ramp Interactive'. You can get it here:

http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/

Of course, considering it is a jQuery library, you will need to also add jQuery library to your project, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: No. This code is not finger gesture, it's mouse event..I don't want mouse event. I need like kinect finger detect and swipe..